# What is a perfect reload in Biomutant?

Tags: biomutant

I found this piece of gear which has a reload perk on it which mentions a Perfect Reload.

[image: Rapid-Fire - Succeeding a perfect Reload increases the rate of fire for the next magazine by 25%]

The game hasn't explained to me what that is yet or how to perform it.

How do I perform a Perfect Reload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect Reload is an action event that triggers a fast reload.

[image]

When your ammo is low, there is a prompt to press a button. This causes your character to reload much faster than normal. This fast reload also triggers the "Perfect Reload" bonus.

A video answer will demonstrate this better so you can look at the details in this video:

Comment: Do you have to buy this perk? I can't see this button prompt

Comment: I don't own the game, so I have no idea. It seems to be a perk though. The video talks about how to get it.